# I turned on developer options and disabled my incoming calls, how do i turn back on?

Tags: developer-options

A while back I enabled developer options and at the time managed to disable my incoming calls. Now I want to enable it again and for the life of me cannot figure out how I did it. Help please!!

Comment: My Developer Options doesn't have any call-related settings, so probably not significant; perhaps you mean you rooted the device? There seems to be a number of ways to do this. If you rooted the phone, then adb would allow disable of system apps; if not rooted, check Call Settings > Call Barring.

Comment: Thanks, im not super tech savvy and always think ill remember what I've done.

Comment: OMG,  call settings/barring. Thank you so much!!!!